# Inject a specific implementation of an interface in a controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I am working on a web application which is built on ASP.NET Core and I am using Autofac for dependency injection.

I have an interface as `ICacheProvider`, and there are 3 concrete implementations of this interface - `OrderCacheProvider`, `ProductsCacheProvider` and `CustomerCacheProvider`. The infrastructure and logic are different for the different cache providers. They are registered as below:

```
builder.RegisterType<CustomerCacheProvider>()
            .Keyed<ICacheProvider>(CacheType.Customer);
builder.RegisterType<OrderCacheProvider>()
            .Keyed<ICacheProvider>(CacheType.Order);
builder.RegisterType<ProductCacheProvider>()
            .Keyed<ICacheProvider>(CacheType.Product);
```

Now I have 3 controllers - `OrdersController`, `ProductsController` and `CustomerController`. Each controller expects an `ICacheProvider` in the below fashion

```
public class OrdersController: BaseController {
    private readonly ICacheProvider _cacheProvider;
    public OrdersController(ICacheProvider cacheProvider) {
         _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
    }
}
```

**Now my problem is how do I inject `OrderCacheProvider` is injected in `OrdersController`? The same goes for the `CustomerCacheProvder` to `CustomersController` and `ProductsCacheProvider`?**

Comment: [This is one of the FAQs.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `WithParameter` method when you register your controller to specify which `ICacheProvider` it should use

```
builder.RegisterType<OrdersController>()
        .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForKeyed<ICacheProvider>(CacheType.Order));
```

Another option would be to use the `KeyFilter` attribute

```
public class OrdersController
{
    public OrdersController([KeyFilter(CacheType.Order)]ICacheProvider cacheProvider)
    { }
}
```

I prefer the first solution than this one which looks more *pure*, your component just has to request `ICacheProvider` nothing more.

Another solution would be to create a custom module that will add the parameter for each controller based on conventions.

```
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);

        if (registration.Activator.LimitType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseController)))
        {
            String controllerName = registration.Activator.LimitType.Name;
            controllerName = controllerName.Substring(0, controllerName.Length - 10);
            if (Enum.TryParse<CacheType>(controllerName, out CacheType cacheType))
            {
                registration.Preparing += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    e.Parameters = new Parameter[]
                                   {
                                      ResolvedParameter.ForKeyed<ICacheProvider>(cacheType)
                                   }
                                   .Concat(e.Parameters);
                };
            }
            else
            {
                // throw, use default cache, do nothing, etc.
                throw new Exception($"No cache found for controller {controllerName}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is more code but you don't have to use the `WithParameter` for every controller registration, it can be great if you have lot of controller. You still have to register the module :

```
builder.RegisterModule<CacheProviderModule>();
```